# How can i create a link in displaytag?

Tags: java, struts2, displaytag

I want to create edit , delete  link in display tag with struts2. How can i do so ?
 If anybody knows please help me ....

i am doing this.

```
<display:column property="id" title="ID" href="details.jsp" paramId="id" />
```

but the link is not going to details.jsp .It doesn't go anywhere . what can be the possible reason

Comment: Where is the link going? What url you see in browser when you click the link?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't go anywhere? What url you see in the browser? Also you can check the view source to see what url generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is done by the following code.

```
<display:column  title="Edit">
                    <s:url id="updateUrl" action="marketing/update.action">
                        <s:param name="id" value="#attr.countrylist.id" />
                    </s:url>
                    <s:a href="%{updateUrl}" theme="ajax"  targets="countrylist">Update</s:a>
                </display:column>
```

Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 8):

You can write your stuff within the  tag like this:

```
<display:table id="row" >
    <display:column property="id" title="ID" paramId="id"  > 
        <a href="details.jsp?${row.id}">Details</a>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

Comment: For me too its not working, link is not visible only printing property

Answer (score 2):

```
<display:table id="listaProgramas" name="programas" uid="tb" 
                                        pagesize="10" export="false" requestURI="/paginarProgramas.do"
                                        class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">

                                    <display:column title="Fecha de creaci&#243;n" property="fechaCreacionFormato" sortable="true"/>
                                    <display:column title="Fecha de modificaci&#243;n" property="fechaModificacionFormato" sortable="true"/>
                                    <display:column title="Empresa" property="nombreGrupoEmpresa"/>
                                    <display:column title="Usuario" property="codUsuarioCreacion"/>
                                    <display:column title="Estado" property="estadoPrograma.descripcion" />
                                    <%if(pageContext.getAttribute("tb") != null && ((Programa)pageContext.getAttribute("tb")).getEstadoPrograma().getId().equals(Constantes.ID_ESTADO_PROGRAMA_PENDIENTE)){ %>
                                    <display:column title="Modificar/Copiar" value="Modificar" url="/modificarCopiarPrograma.do" paramId="idPrograma" paramProperty="id"  style="text-align:center;"/>  
                                    <%}%> 
                                    <%if(pageContext.getAttribute("tb") != null && ((Programa)pageContext.getAttribute("tb")).getEstadoPrograma().getId().equals(Constantes.ID_ESTADO_PROGRAMA_CERRADO)){ %>
                                        <display:column title="Modificar/Copiar" value="Copiar" url="/modificarCopiarPrograma.do" paramId="idPrograma" paramProperty="id" style="text-align:center;"/>                                       
                                    <%}%>
                                    <display:column title="Reporte Financiero" value="XLS" url="/generarExcel.do" paramId="idPrograma" paramProperty="id" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <img src="image/excel.gif" alt="Descargar Excel"></img>
                                    </display:column>                                     
                                    <display:column title="Reporte Financiero PDF" value="PDF" url="/downloadPDF.do" paramId="idPrograma" paramProperty="id" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <img src="image/excel.gif" alt="Descargar Excel"></img>
                                    </display:column>
                                    </display:table>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It helps if you explain your answer in words a little bit in addition to just dumping the code.

Comment: This answer using url, paramId and paramProperty is the best

Answer (score 1):

You may have to be more specific in order to get better answers. Is the problem understanding struts2 or display tags?  [This tutorial](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_links.html) expains how to create links in display tags library.

If struts 2 is the problem then you could make you question more specific and we'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a decorator for the table and have it generate the link. 
See example below on some other forum:
http://sourceforge.net/forum/message.php?msg_id=4119964